# create autocomplete combobox and textbox without distinct the result C#.net

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-4.1

```
    private void LoadData()
    {
        MedicalCustomersDBEntities db = new MedicalCustomersDBEntities();
        CustomerList = db.Customers;
        AutoCompleteStringCollection completeSource = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

        completeSource.AddRange(CustomerList.Select(ar => " " + ar.FirstName).ToArray());
        completeSource.AddRange(CustomerList.Select(ar => ar.FirstName).ToArray());
        this.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
        this.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        this.AutoCompleteCustomSource = completeSource;
    }
```

I use this code to load all my customers. But when I have two customers with the same name the autocomplete  textbox make distinct for result.

Is there a way to show all result.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make use of distinct in the query itself.

<strike>CustomerList = db.Customers.Name.Distinct();</strike>

I don't have a PC, but you can try something like that....The above code is not right

Comment: thanks Pankaj Upadhyay , but I need some things opposite of distinct